# Endless redirect after editing question

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Very unusual: after rolling back a useless edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651672/pdophp-execquery-fail-to-update-a-char-type-value), I am no longer able to access it. The browser gives up with:

```
too many redirects occurred trying to open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651672/pdophp-execquery-fail-to-update-a-char-type-value
```

I cannot access this URL using any approach; not from my profile's activity list, directly, using a shortened `https://stackoverflow.com/q/30651672` or anything. This is OS X Safari (latest).

On another browser where I'm *not logged in*, or simply curl, it works just fine.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaand it's solved by opening the web inspector trying to investigate this issue... guess that reset some cache or something... Still, leaving this here for a moment, maybe it's a useful report to somebody.

Comment: Weird. Something gone haywire locally?

Comment: I wonder. Never encountered that before.